# Shiny Leaflet Map Popups Are Pulling the Wrong Data

Tags: r, leaflet, shiny, shiny-server

For some reason, the popups assigned to the polygons on the Shiny leaflet app are pulling up the wrong information that should be assigned to the polygon.  It seems that the Polygons have been placed on the map, then assigned the polygon attributes in a different order.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
server<-function(input,output,session)({

  output$map<-renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
        addTiles() %>%
        addPolygons(data = spatial_merge, 
          layerId = spatial_merge@data$PolygonNo, 
          stroke= TRUE, fillOpacity = 0.5, smoothFactor = 0.5,     weight=1,
          color = "grey", opacity = 1, popup=paste(sep= "<br/>",
               "<b>ForestName: </b>", spatial_merge$ForestName,
               "<b>Project Name: </b>", spatial_merge$Project_Name,
               "<b>Treatment Year: </b>", spatial_merge$Project_Year,
               "<b>Treatment Type: </b>", spatial_merge$Treatment_Type,
               "<b>Area Treated: </b>", spatial_merge$Polygon_Area,
               "<b>Polygon Cost: </b>", spatial_merge$TotalCost,
               "<b>Contractor Name: </b>", spatial_merge$Project_Contractor)
  })
})    

shinyApp(ui,server)

> class(spatial_merge)
[1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"

> names(spatial_merge)
 [1] "Primary_Key"        "Project_Name"       "PolygonNo"          "WMA"                    "ContractName"       "Project_Year"      
 [7] "Treatment_Type"     "Project_Contractor" "Polygon_Area"           "TotalCost"          "OBJECTID_12"        "FA_NAME"           
[13] "Comments"           "Source"             "DataCaptureDate"        "DataCapturedBy"     "Block_ID"           "SubBlock_ID"       
[19] "SHAPE_Length"       "SHAPE_Area"   

> dim(spatial_merge)
[1] 647  20
```

Thanks for looking at my question!
K

Comment: It's hard to know for sure without seeing the structure of your data, but I'm not sure if you need the `$` in the popup code. Can you try without it?

Comment: @Jim Leach I updated with the type of data.  The $ didn't manage to solve the problem unfortunately

Comment: Try creating the popup first as a separate object: `popup <- paste(sep = ..., )` and then using that object directly in the `addPolygons()` call. I'm afraid I've only ever used leaflet with `data.frame` data, so I'm not sure how it behaves with sp data.

Comment: haha man, I also tried that method.  It seems that the sp data is acting a little differently...

Comment: Your code inside the `renderLeaflet` call seems fine. Obviously I don't have your data, but with a data set from mapview the feature IDs of the polygons are fine. See this gist:
https://gist.github.com/tim-salabim/9d132266609f49ae13688595eab04d21

Comment: Are you able to share the data, or something that looks like it?

Comment: @JimLeach I'll try to put something together.  It's quite odd though, TimSalabim was totally right that the code works using the mapview data...but mine doesn't.  It's almost like the polygons are being shuffled and then its' associated attribute table is being shuffled in a different way and then being put on the map.  I'll try to get you some data.  Do you have an email?

Comment: You can reach me on jim at thedatagent dot com

Comment: Was this problem actually solved? I would like to see the resolution.

Comment: @Konrad Unfortunately no, I spent a decent amount of time trying to figure it out, but then had to move onto other things at work :(.  I'm still super interested in figuring it out though.

Comment: @AlphaKevy OK,  I will have a look. It may be useful to update your post with the details on how the `spatial_merge` is created. For instance, I presume that the advisable way to merge the data into a `sp` object would involve making use of the `sp::merge`.

Comment: Has this ever been resolved? I'm facing the same issue when using SF library then leaflet. Mapview shows the correct polygon labels, but leaflet does not. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74976789/r-leaflet-incorrect-polygon-label-after-st-intersection